# How to make gifs/ which app to use?

Tags: 16.04, photoshop, gif

I used to make gifs with Photoshop CS5 (oldie, I know) and I want to do it again but now I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. 
Do you have any recommendations about apps similar to PS and maybe some tutorials? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're asking for a software recommendation, which is handled by http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com .You also have not specified if you want still GIFs (which any graphics program can output) or _animated_ GIFs. You may alsoo find a helpful list for Linux at https://alternativeto.net/browse/search/?q=photoshop&ignoreExactMatch=true&platform=linux

Comment: I would prefer to have **any question** specific to Ubuntu shown here. That is why I come to **Ask Ubuntu** and not How to Geek, etc.

Comment: @K7AAY: Help Center > Asking states: Questions that you may ask:    Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.

Comment: You will note others voted this closed as well. Bless your heart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [gimp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EPIUyFJ4ag) as an alternative:

```
sudo apt install snap
sudo snap install gimp --stable
```

But you could also install Photoshop using wine and PlayOnLinux.

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```